# How long after appending dynamic html do you have access to it?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to access the height of a parent div after new divs are dynamically added to it.

I'm finding, in testing,  that if I check the height of one of the children immediately after

```
$("#myParent").append(rO); (where rO holds all my newly create HTML)
```

checking it's height turns up 0, even though there is definitely something in the div.

If I check the height in a function run by a button afterwards, the height shows up.

How soon after appending something can you access it's height?

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it on the same line if you want to, here's an example:

```
$('#test').append('<div id="tester">lol hai</div>').find('#tester').addClass('active').html($('#tester').outerHeight());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v42rV/3/

Comment: Thanks guys. Is it possible to do it if you have the parent div hidden? I'm trying to get the height of it before I show it. I'm testing, and it seems the height can only be accessed after you've done $('#yourDiv').show(); on anything you've dynamically added to 'yourDiv'

Comment: That's bizarre - I tested hiding the div first on your jsfiddle, and it still works fine. If I run mine, it will only show a height if I place show() after appending - $("#myDiv").append(rO); $('#myDiv').show();

Comment: That's probably because I have my height set in the CSS, the height in my example is not dynamic. If I take out the CSS heights on both the parent and it's child it matches what you are experiencing, though I am able to get the height of the parent "18", http://jsfiddle.net/v42rV/6/ 

If you do want to do it like this, a good work around is to show the content first and get the height then (but position it so it's off the page), then reset the position & hide it after you've got the height. Then your height will be available to be stored in a variable.

Comment: Phew - thought I was going nuts. I've been battling this for about 4 hours!!! Thanks Joe!

Answer (score 1):

Immediately Right  after we add something look at this example as content is generated height also changes

[See this Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7CP94/)

### Jquery

```
$( "#myParent" ).click(function() {
$("#myParent").append("dsa ContentContentContentContentContent");
alert($('#myParent').height() );
});
```

### Html

```
<div id="myParent">

dsa
</div>
```